# How do I navigate between files in the preview app of OS X?

Tags: image, macos, preview

I have some images inside a folder, and I double click one of them to open a preview app to show the image. Now I want to go to the next image, I have to go to that folder again and double click the next image. 
Is there any easy way like press `next` button to show the next image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do something similar to programs like IrfanView on Windows is to select all images in Finder and hit cmd+o, which opens Preview with all images in the sidebar. This can be navigated using the arrow keys.

Answer (score 0):

Select all images and Double click over selected items.